# Prolog predicate single node in tree

Tags: prolog

Code a predicate that finds all nodes in the tree with exactly one single child node.
Given the tree

```
treeEx(X) :-
    X = t(73,t(31,t(5,nil,nil),nil),t(101,t(83,nil,t(97,nil,nil)),nil)).
```

```
     73
    /  \
  31   101
 /     /
5     83
     /   
    97
```

It should return `L = [31, 101, 83]`

I have tried the following, but it returns all nodes. I do not know how to list only the single child nodes.

```
single(nil,[]).
single(t(X,L,R),[X|S]) :- 
   append(SL,SR,S), single(L,SL), single(R,SR).
```

Comment: What does the condition for a single child node look like? Isn't it either the right is `nil` but the left is not, or *vice versa*? Your code doesn't enforce that condition anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [..] a predicate that finds all nodes in the tree with exactly one single child node.

First think about which cases You're interested in:

- `t(V,nil,R)` := a node with value `V` and a single (right) child `R`.
- `t(V,L,nil)` := a node with value `V` and a single (left) child `L`.

Then think about the other cases, which You're not interested in (in as general terms as possible):

- `t(V,nil,nil)` := a node with value `V` and no children.
- `t(V,L,R)` := a node with value `V` and both a left (`L`) and right (`R`) child.

Next think about what You want to "do": *Collect* the values of the cases You're interested in in a list. Thus, when You have a case You're interested in, then You'd need to add the value `V` to a list with Your results:

```
[V|RestResults] % whatever RestResults is, not important atm
```

With that, You can write Your predicate: You know it has one "input" parameter (the tree) and one "output" parameter (the list). First the cases You're interested in:

```
single(t(V, nil, R), [V|Vr]) :- single(R, Vr).
single(t(V, L, nil), [V|Vl]) :- single(L, Vl).
```

You add the value `V` to the results (list of values) You get from the single child branch.

Next the cases You're not interested in. First the easy one:

```
single(t(_,nil,nil), []).
```

That's a leaf node (no children). Its value isn't interesting, and there are no results that might come from its children, so the result list is the empty list.

Finally, the most complex case:

```
single(t(_, L, R), X) :- single(L, Vl), single(R, Vr), append(Vl, Vr, X).
```

Two children; the value isn't interesting in this case, but the children are: You need to gather *their* result lists and append them to create the result list of this node.

Now, the order in which You write these rules is *normally* important in Prolog, but in this case the order doesn't matter (when Prolog uses the "wrong" rule for a node, e.g. the last one - two children - for a `t(_,nil,nil)`, then it quickly arrives in a situation - `single(nil, _)` - where no rule matches, and backtracks to the "correct" rule). Nonetheless I'd sort the rules according to how "specific" their pattern is: First the rule for no children, then the two for one child, and finally the one for two children.

([Live](https://ideone.com/PMvoDi) on ideone)